# Как сравнить суму выдачи результатов на странице с числом total, если таких результатов может быть сколько угодно

Tags: c#, selenium

Суть в следующем: в строку поиска вводится строка, после сабмита получаем некоторое количество разделов, в которых найдена наша строка. В зависимости от строки, которую ищем, таких результатов может быть разное количество. Я полагаю, тут надо как то их всех перебрать в цикле. Как мне программно обратиться ко всем элементам, которые представляют количество найденых совпадений в разделах, суммировать их и сравнить с количеством всех найденных результатов (в данном случае найдено 5536 результатов и всего два раздела, содержащих строку "лист" 719 и 1282 раза, как указано на скриншоте).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: собрать все, суммировать, сравнивать

Comment: а можно верстку блока результатов поиска или сылку на данную страницу?

Comment: да, пожалуйста, добавьте пример вёрстки сайта, и конечно же тот код, который вы уже написали, что-бы нам было с чего начать (то есть с чего продолжить ваш код). Потому что без этого, комментарий @Senior Pomidor описывает в целом всё что вам нужно сделать и в текущем варианте вашего вопроса, такой комментарий можно отметить как ответ.